# Dataweave transformation in mule4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

The payload transformation should be as follows:

Input:

{

"First": "Mark",

"Last" : "John"

}

Output:

{

"Result" : " MJaorhkn"

}

The required output should be the alternating combination of values in key value pair

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-zip) here

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var first = payload.First splitBy ""
var last = payload.Last splitBy ""
---
"Result":flatten(first zip last) joinBy ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use map to loop through each character of your string and use the index to access characters that you wanted.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var First = payload.First splitBy  ""
var Last = payload.Last splitBy  ""
---

{
    Result: First map ($ ++ Last[$$]) joinBy ""
}
```

This will result to:

```
{
  "Result": "MJaorhkn"
}
```